# Ping a hostname Linux desde Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

Tanto en Debian como en Ubuntu, cuando hago una instalación mínima, las máquinas NO responden desde Windows10 a un:

```
ping hostname
```

En cambio, cuando les instalo LAMP, MariaDB y demás aplicaciones de red sí que responden. Lo que me hace pensar que habrá alguna aplicación o configuración que habilite que se puedan identificar por DNS en la red de área local y Windows los reconozca.

Como obtienen su dirección IP por DHCP, esta funcionalidad es comodísima para acceder a éstas máquinas por SSH, RDP, SMB o HTTP sin necesidad de conocer su IP.

Curiosamente, desde los diferentes sistemas Linux que he probado, da igual lo completa que sea la instalación, nunca los identifica por el hostname y tengo que recurrir siempre a la IP.

¿Alguna sugerencia de por dónde empezar a mirar?

Comment: mmm pero esta pregunta que tiene que ver con desarrollo de software?

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo: es de sistemas y redes. Pero lo necesitaba para poder programar y ya estaba frito de teclear la IP en cada conexión :)

Comment: habria un sitio de linux para esas cosas ;)

Comment: ¿Te refieres a https://askubuntu.com/ ? ¿Hay también en español?

Comment: no.. solo en ingles... (ojo igual no voy a borrar la pregunta ni nada... pero si alguien empieza... )

Comment: Yo soy técnico en sistemas microinformáticos y redes es un medio y estoy terminando el superior y lo que suele pasar con Windows es que a contrario que Ubuntu bloquea todo por lo que debes añadir una regla en el firewall de Windows o desactivarlo y añadir la ip con el nombre que deseas del host en el fichero hosts de Windows

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de dar con ello: no he tenido más que instalar el `samba`

```
$ sudo apt install samba
```

En este [enlace](https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/73898/hacer-ping-a-ubuntu-por-nombre-de-host-en-una-maquina-windows) he obtenido varias pistas, por lo visto SMB comunica los hostname por NetBIOS y WINS y permite que los sistemas Windows detecten a las máquinas Linux.

Para que también las localice desde los Linux, en este otro [enlace](https://qastack.mx/ubuntu/507649/ubuntu-can-not-ping-host-name-but-can-ping-ip) he localizado cómo resolverlo:

```
$ sudo apt install libnss-winbind
$ sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Añado `wins` al final de la línea `hosts: files dns` y reinicio el servicio:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart winbind
```